# Bibliography natdin - why strange blank spaces and wordwraps?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using the natdin for my bibliography, and it works pretty well, but there are a few strange effects. In the picture you can see what I mean. Sometimes, it adds a blank space between things, where no blank space should be.

For example, if you have a book with multiple authors.

And the other thing is, that it adds a blank space between the address, and the ":" after which the year follows.

Third, there are strange wordwraps, e.g. in the ISBN-numbers.

What can I do against that? I did not add the spaces in my bibliography, natdin added these. How to change that?

Thanks!!

[image: bibliography]

EDIT: Alright, I think the blank space which is inserted after an author, if there are different authors, is ok. I found it very strange, but I think it's done like that very often, maybe for readability.
But the blank space at the adress part is really strange...

Comment: i can't answer about the spaces, but the line break in the isbn is to be expected.  it's clear that the bibliography is justified, and to keep it justified, if the isbn were *not* broken at a hyphen, the only other place to break the line would be before or after "ISBN", and then the spacing would be unacceptably uneven.

Comment: okay alright. That's kind of acceptable ;)

Comment: i've taken a look at `natdin.bst`.  there are several instances of "space semicolon" to be placed between names -- for the functions `format.names`, `format.editors`, `format.editors.organization`, and `format.crossref.editor`.  since the file `natdin.bst` is in a directory identified as `din1505`, and the introductory comments in the file refer to that din 1505, teil 2 and 3, i guess that this formatting is a requirement of that standard.  (doesn't make any sense to me why it's that way, but standards are sometimes like that.)

Comment: alright, thanks!
I also found the position of the declaration " :" in the .bst file, if I like I can change that to ":", without the blank space. (Already tried it) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(the author of the question has gotten past this hurdle, and has asked another question: [Bibliography natdin.bst - how to add period instead of comma?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304326/579). the purpose of this answer is just to keep an unanswered question from hanging around.)

regarding the line break in the isbn, this  is to be expected. it's clear
that the bibliography is justified, and to keep it justified, if the isbn
were *not* broken at a hyphen, the only other place to break the line would
be before or after "ISBN", and then the spacing would be unacceptably uneven.

in `natdin.bst`. there are several instances of "space semicolon" to be
placed between names -- for the functions `format.names`, `format.editors`,
`format.editors.organization`, and `format.crossref.editor`.

since the file `natdin.bst` is in a directory identified as `din1505`, and
the introductory comments in the file refer to that din 1505, teil 2 and 3,
i guess that this formatting is a requirement of that standard. (doesn't
make any sense to me why it's that way, but standards are sometimes like
that.)